# make library not found

Tags: macos, makefile, environment-variables, omnet++

I'm trying to compile a program using a third party library, Omnet++ in my case. Apparently "make" does not find a library, but the path it uses is correct as you can see (in the sense that I can see the library under omnet++ source tree)

```
    pv135168:basic Bob$ opp_makemake    
Creating Makefile in /Users/Bob/Code/network_sim/basic... Makefile created, running "make depend" to add dependencies... opp_makedep -Y --objdirtree -I. -f Makefile -P\$O/ --   ./*.cc   

    pv135168:basic Bob$ make   
    g++ -c -g -Wall
        -fno-stack-protector   -m32  -DHAVE_PCAP -DXMLPARSER=libxml
        -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER  -I.
        -I/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/include -o out/gcc-debug//txc1.o txc1.cc g++ -m32 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib -Wl,-rpath,. -o out/gcc-debug//basic  out/gcc-debug//txc1.o  -Wl,-all_load  
        -L"/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib/gcc"
        -L"/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib" -u _tkenv_lib -lopptkenvd
        -loppenvird -lopplayoutd -u _cmdenv_lib -loppcmdenvd -loppenvird 
        -loppsimd -lstdc++   
     ld: library not found for -lopptkenvd   
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [out/gcc-debug//basic]   
    Error 1 pv135168:basic Bob$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking in the following directories for a file called `libopptkenvd.dylib` or `libopptkenvd.a`:

```
/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib/gcc
/Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib
```

Is that file in one of those directories (or in the standard directories like `/usr/lib`)? I don't see an indication of that in your output.

Comment: Sorry... Windows development on the brain. Yes, dylib (fixed). Can you double-check `ls /Users/Bob/Code/omnetpp-4.1/lib/libopptkenvd.dylib` and make sure that really returns something (and that it's not empty)? The linker is telling you it's not there.

Comment: I see, the real name of the library is libopptkenv.dylib not libopptkenvd.dylib. Strange it must be a typo generated somehow in the makefile..